# How to display a navbar component after logging in without reloading the page in angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

***My landing page does not show a navbar, but I want to display a navbar after logging in successfully.  Currently, I'm able to show navbar if I do a full page reload after logging in successfully.*** I'm very sure that there is a better way than this approach.

---

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

---

**login.component.ts**

```js
login(){
    this.credentials = this.myForm.value;
    if(this.credentials){
      this.loginService.authenticate(this.credentials)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.storageService.setLocalStorageItem('auth', JSON.stringify(data));
        this.dataService.global.showNav = true;
        this.sharedService.getProjectMetadata()
        .subscribe(metadata => {
          this.storageService.setLocalStorageItem('projectMetaData', JSON.stringify(metadata));
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        })
      }, err => console.log(err));
    } else {
      console.log('Please enter your username and password');
    }
  }
```

---

**data.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IGlobal, IMessage } from '../../Shared/interfaces';
import { MessageCallback } from '../../Shared/types';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  constructor() { }

  date: string = (new Date()).toString();

  global: IGlobal = {
    showNav: false,
    sessionTimedOut: false,
    timezone: this.date.substring(this.date.indexOf('GMT')),
    projectMetaData: {
      name: ''
    },
    isAdmin: false,
    auth: {
      roles: {
        admin: false,
        developer: false
      }
    }
  }

  private handler: Subject<IMessage> = new Subject<IMessage>();

  broadcast(type: string, payload: any){
    this.handler.next({type, payload});
  }

  subscribe(type: string, callback: MessageCallback): Subscription {
    return this.handler.pipe(filter(message => message.type === type), map(message => message.payload))
                        .subscribe(callback);
  }
}
```

---

**navbar.component.html**

```html
<mat-toolbar fxLayout="row" color="primary" *ngIf='showNavbar'></mat-toolbar>
```

---

**navbar.component.ts**

```js
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  user: IAuth = {};
  showNavbar: boolean;
  progressbar: number = 0;

  constructor(
    private storageService: StorageService,
    private dataService: DataService
  ) { 
    this.showNavbar = this.dataService.global.showNav;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = JSON.parse(this.storageService.getLocalStorageItem('auth'));
    if(this.user){
      this.showNavbar = true;
    }
  }

}
```

Please help me out. Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here,

- once authentication is completed successfully in login() function, it is not communicated to `navbar.component.ts`
- `showNavbar` in `navbar.component.ts` is used to display/hide navbar template.
- Though dataService.global.showNav is set to true, it will not trigger change detection in navbar components. Since it is copied to `showNavbar' only in constructor.
- So before login, navbar is already loaded, probably with `showNavbar` evaluated as false, and never recomputed until page reload.
- During pagereload value is read from localStorage which provides latest value to `showNavbar`

I have two suggestions{S1,S2} to fix this.

#### S1.

1.broadcast via subject from login component about successful login status
2.And subscribe for that status in navbar component and upon subscription , control rendering of navbar template
3. Looks like as per your business logic,`broadcast` and `subscribe` functions in dataservice does that for you in IMessage type subject.
4. Consider example code below and update according to your application.
For eg:
`login.component.ts`

```
this.dataService.broadcast('authSuccess',{auth:'successful'})
```

in `navbar.component.ts`

```
OnInit() {
   this.dataService.subscribe('authSuccess',setShowNavbar);
}
setShowNavbar() {
  this.showNavbar=true;
}
```

#### S2:

This is not a clean approach and difficult for tracking, but it works for quick and dirty solutions.

`navbar.component.html`

```
<mat-toolbar fxLayout="row" color="primary" *ngIf="dataService.global.showNav"></mat-toolbar>
```

This case will run change detection whenever value in dataService.global.showNav is updated and evaluate ngIf accordingly.
Note: Better to add a small working proto in stackblitz/jsfiddle/codesandbox etc when posting questions in public forum. So it will be easier for everyone to identify exact problem and arrive on specific solutions quickly.